# How to merge two arrays based on same index with same index

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge

Actually i have two arrays as given below

```
$array1=array('0'=>'abc','1'=>'xyz');
$array2=array('0'=>'pqr','1'=>'mno');
```

I want to two arrays first created with key[0] and second with key[1]. means should look like as follow

```
$a1=array('0'=>'abc','1'=>'pqr');
$a2=array('0'=>'xyz','1'=>'mno');
```

The result must be

```
$a1 = array (
 '0' => $array1[0],
 '1' => $array2[0]
);

$a2 = array (
 '0' => $array1[1],
 '1' => $array2[1]
);
```

Comment: What have you done so far to achieve your goal?

Comment: what do you want the array to look like in the final result? can u make an example?

Comment: @sietse85 Second code, after "_means should look like as follow_"

Comment: i have written above $a1 and $a2 derived from $array1 and $array2

Comment: `$a1=array('0'=>$array1[0],'1'=>$array2[0]);
$a2=array('0'=>$array1[1],'1'=>$array2[1]);`

Comment: if i have more array then what i should do

Comment: this is confusing me, to me it looks like you want just to make a copy of the array?

Comment: @MohdHasan You'll have to write a proper question so we can all understand what you need. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @sietse85 When you aren't sure about the question, always seek clarification from OP prior to answer or you'll end-up wasting your time ;-)

Comment: Would you mind having a single array like `array(array('abc', 'pqr'), array('xyz', 'mno'))`? If that is okay, then `array_map(null, $array1, $array2)` will get you that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try this code

```
<?php

$array1=array('0'=>'abc','1'=>'xyz');
$array2=array('0'=>'pqr','1'=>'mno');

foreach($array1 as $key => $val){
    $array_name = "a".($key + 1);
    ${$array_name} = array();
    ${$array_name}[0] = $array1[$key];
    ${$array_name}[1] = $array2[$key];
}

var_dump($a1);
var_dump($a2);
```