# php array of array merge

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I have these two arrays:

niceviewA Array (

```
[0] => Array ( [dow] => Monday [goalamount] => 1000.00 ) 
[1] => Array ( [dow] => Tuesday [goalamount] => 1000.00 ) 
[2] => Array ( [dow] => Wednesday [goalamount] => 1500.00 ) 
[3] => Array ( [dow] => Thursday [goalamount] => 1800.00 ) 
[4] => Array ( [dow] => Friday [goalamount] => 1800.00 ) 
[5] => Array ( [dow] => Saturday [goalamount] => 2000.00 ) 
[6] => Array ( [dow] => Sunday [goalamount] => 1500.00 ) )
```

and this
actualNet Array (

```
[0] => Array ( [dow] => Friday [NetSales] => 1542.56 [ClosingBarTender] => Bill [OtherBartenders] => Jeremy,Rilee ) 
[1] => Array ( [dow] => Thursday [NetSales] => 1219.89 [ClosingBarTender] => Bill [OtherBartenders] => Vic ) 
[2] => Array ( [dow] => Wednesday [NetSales] => 1019.9 [ClosingBarTender] => Cora [OtherBartenders] => Tory ) 
[3] => Array ( [dow] => Tuesday [NetSales] => 1317.44 [ClosingBarTender] => Bill [OtherBartenders] => Bill ) 
[4] => Array ( [dow] => Monday [NetSales] => 907.85 [ClosingBarTender] => Rilee [OtherBartenders] => Bill ) 
[5] => Array ( [dow] => Sunday [NetSales] => 1954.84 [ClosingBarTender] => Rilee [OtherBartenders] => Ginger ) 
[6] => Array ( [dow] => Saturday [NetSales] => 2496.28 [ClosingBarTender] => Rilee [OtherBartenders] => LJ,Ginger ) )
```

I used **array_replace_recursive**, but that just joined them on index, I need to join them on the 'dow' element, so it would look like this:

actualNet Array (

```
[0] => Array ( [dow] => Friday [NetSales] => 1542.56 [ClosingBarTender] => Bill [OtherBartenders] => Jeremy,Rilee [goalamount] => 1800.00) 
[1] => Array ( [dow] => Thursday [NetSales] => 1219.89 [ClosingBarTender] => Bill [OtherBartenders] => Vic [goalamount] => 1800.00) 
[2] => Array ( [dow] => Wednesday [NetSales] => 1019.9 [ClosingBarTender] => Cora [OtherBartenders] => Tory [goalamount] => 1500.00) 
[3] => Array ( [dow] => Tuesday [NetSales] => 1317.44 [ClosingBarTender] => Bill [OtherBartenders] => Bill [goalamount] => 1000.00) 
[4] => Array ( [dow] => Monday [NetSales] => 907.85 [ClosingBarTender] => Rilee [OtherBartenders] => Bill [goalamount] => 1000.00) 
[5] => Array ( [dow] => Sunday [NetSales] => 1954.84 [ClosingBarTender] => Rilee [OtherBartenders] => Ginger[goalamount] => 1500.00 ) 
[6] => Array ( [dow] => Saturday [NetSales] => 2496.28 [ClosingBarTender] => Rilee [OtherBartenders] => LJ,Ginger [goalamount] => 20000.00) )
```

Not like this:
niceview2Array (

```
[0] => Array ( [dow] => Friday [goalamount] => 1000.00 [NetSales] => 1542.56 [ClosingBarTender] => Bill [OtherBartenders] => Jeremy,Rilee ) 
[1] => Array ( [dow] => Thursday [goalamount] => 1000.00 [NetSales] => 1219.89 [ClosingBarTender] => Bill [OtherBartenders] => Vic ) 
[2] => Array ( [dow] => Wednesday [goalamount] => 1500.00 [NetSales] => 1019.9 [ClosingBarTender] => Cora [OtherBartenders] => Tory ) 
[3] => Array ( [dow] => Tuesday [goalamount] => 1800.00 [NetSales] => 1317.44 [ClosingBarTender] => Bill [OtherBartenders] => Bill ) 
[4] => Array ( [dow] => Monday [goalamount] => 1800.00 [NetSales] => 907.85 [ClosingBarTender] => Rilee [OtherBartenders] => Bill ) 
[5] => Array ( [dow] => Sunday [goalamount] => 2000.00 [NetSales] => 1954.84 [ClosingBarTender] => Rilee [OtherBartenders] => Ginger ) 
[6] => Array ( [dow] => Saturday [goalamount] => 1500.00 [NetSales] => 2496.28 [ClosingBarTender] => Rilee [OtherBartenders] => LJ,Ginger ) )
```

I have tried to iterate through the arrays, but I can’t get a match on ‘dow’.  I’m so frustrated I have come to stackoverflow and hope some one can help!  Thanks so much!

Comment: Show us the code you used to itereate through the arrays

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49831781/how-to-merge-two-arrays-based-on-same-index-with-same-index

Comment: That isn't the same @MohdHasan.  The arrays I am now merging based on the answer below works.  I have an array in an array and was not doing it correctly.  Thanks for all of your replies.  About the code that didn't work, I would have to go back a few versions of my code to find it.

Comment: I would be using a couple of `array_column()` calls to prepare the data for an `array_replace_recursive()` call as I demonstrate at the duplicate page.  If you have some pressing urge to micro-optimize and require nested foreach traversal, then you can use Shiv's snippet more performantly with a `break` in the inner loop and without the `array_merge()` or `array_values()` calls.  https://3v4l.org/mSkhQ

Answer (score 0):

```
$first = [ ['dow' => 'Monday' , 'goalamount' => 1000.00 ],
        ['dow' => 'Tuesday' , 'goalamount' => 1500.00 ],
        ['dow' => 'Wednesday' , 'goalamount' => 1800.00 ],
        ['dow' => 'Thursday' , 'goalamount' => 1800.00 ],
        ['dow' => 'Friday' , 'goalamount' => 2000.00 ],
        ['dow' => 'Saturday' , 'goalamount' => 1500.00 ],
        ['dow' => 'Sunday' , 'goalamount' => 1500.00 ],
    ];
    $second = [ [ 'dow' => 'Friday', 'NetSales' => 1542.56, 'ClosingBarTender' => 'Bill', 'OtherBartenders' => 'Jeremy,Rilee'],
        [ 'dow' => 'Thursday', 'NetSales' => 1219.89, 'ClosingBarTender' => 'Bill', 'OtherBartenders' => 'Vic'],
        [ 'dow' => 'Wednesday', 'NetSales' => 1019.9, 'ClosingBarTender' => 'Cora', 'OtherBartenders' => 'Tory'],
        [ 'dow' => 'Tuesday', 'NetSales' => 1317.44, 'ClosingBarTender' => 'Bill', 'OtherBartenders' => 'Bill'],
        [ 'dow' => 'Monday', 'NetSales' => 907.85, 'ClosingBarTender' => 'Rilee', 'OtherBartenders' => 'Bill'],
        [ 'dow' => 'Sunday', 'NetSales' => 1954.84, 'ClosingBarTender' => 'Rilee', 'OtherBartenders' => 'Ginger'],
        [ 'dow' => 'Saturday', 'NetSales' => 2496.28, 'ClosingBarTender' => 'Rilee', 'OtherBartenders' => 'JLJ,Ginger'],
    ];
    $result = [];
     foreach( $second as $key => $value) {
         foreach($first as $v ) {
            if($value['dow'] == $v['dow']) {
                $result[$value['dow']] = array_merge($value, [ 'goalamount'=> $v['goalamount'] ] ) ;
            }
       }
   }
        print_r(array_values($result));
```

Output:

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [dow] => Friday
            [NetSales] => 1542.56
            [ClosingBarTender] => Bill
            [OtherBartenders] => Jeremy,Rilee
            [goalamount] => 2000
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [dow] => Thursday
            [NetSales] => 1219.89
            [ClosingBarTender] => Bill
            [OtherBartenders] => Vic
            [goalamount] => 1800
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [dow] => Wednesday
            [NetSales] => 1019.9
            [ClosingBarTender] => Cora
            [OtherBartenders] => Tory
            [goalamount] => 1800
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [dow] => Tuesday
            [NetSales] => 1317.44
            [ClosingBarTender] => Bill
            [OtherBartenders] => Bill
            [goalamount] => 1500
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [dow] => Monday
            [NetSales] => 907.85
            [ClosingBarTender] => Rilee
            [OtherBartenders] => Bill
            [goalamount] => 1000
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [dow] => Sunday
            [NetSales] => 1954.84
            [ClosingBarTender] => Rilee
            [OtherBartenders] => Ginger
            [goalamount] => 1500
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [dow] => Saturday
            [NetSales] => 2496.28
            [ClosingBarTender] => Rilee
            [OtherBartenders] => JLJ,Ginger
            [goalamount] => 1500
        )

)
```

Comment: thanks so much!  I think I was missing the array_merge when I iterated through the array.

Comment: I did vote the answer, alas I don't have the reputation to have it publicly viewed.